# How can I save an existing custom bullet style?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, bullets

I'm modifying an existing PPTX file that I downloaded, and I like the custom style of a bullet.

When I try to create a new bullet list, that custom style isn't available. I don't have the PNG for it and so can't create it.

Can I somehow save the custom style, so I can use it on new lists?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share with us this PPTX file and which bullet is it?

Comment: Here's a link to the file. I hope it works. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1kDHMOYBPkN1uJAdnP7k688a1oPtLMNJ3/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108082471811943423531&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bullet style is a photo, and I do not think there is an official way to export/save it from PowerPoint. (PowerPoint doesn't even have a way to reuse it - add it the to the menu of available bullet list designs - within the same PTTX file.)

But here is the photo file from this custom bullet list (exported from the PPTX file's resources):
[image]

(You can also have both PPTX files open at the same time and copy-paste one such bulleted list into the new file, and it will copy it as a bullet list style.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!